# Inaccessible-encryption-credentials status of AWS RDS instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-kms

when i tried to access the AWS RDS instance, i could see the status of RDS instance as `Inaccessible-encryption-credentials` .But the key key is available in KMS(Key Managed Service). How can i retrieve the instance ?

how can i  make the instance available ?

Comment: It might be that "RDS access to a KMS key is revoked". See: [Encrypting Amazon RDS resources - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.Encryption.html)

Answer (score 0):

If that is `Inaccessible-encryption-credentials-recoverable` simply go into AWS>RDS>Databases and choose the instance and click on edit on top right , then start.